# How can I get the probability of an event happening on a day, given the probability of it happening in a year?

Tags: probability

I want to model the probability of a person in a country taking a plane. I know the number of people who take a plane in that country in a year (N) and the population of that country (M). So I think I could model the probability of a person in that country taking a plane in a year as:

$p = \frac{N}{M}$

How can I know the probability of a person taking a plane in one day?

I accept assumptions of the model to simplify the problem as:

- The event of a person taking a plane is independent of another person taking a plane.
- Any person takes a plane only once a year.

Comment: Divide $p$ by 365?

Comment: This is unanswerable as stated, because you need information about things like how many times per year individuals take the plane.  As an example, imagine a country in which everybody who has a job flies to work and otherwise they stay home: in a stable economy, the chance per day is the same as the chance per year.

Comment: @IgorF. That won't get you the right number. Suppose there's a 365/1000 chance of taking a plane in a year. By your method, the chance of taking a plane in a day is 1/1000, but then the chance of taking a plane in a year is 1 - ((1-1/1000) ^365), which is only 30.5%, but it should be 36.5%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the probability of a person taking a plane in a year is `p`, then the probability of someone *not* taking a plane that year is `1-p`
A person *not taking a plane in a year* means that for 365 consecutive days that person did not take a plane. be `n` the probability of someone not taking a plane in any given day, we have
n^365 = 1-p
or
n = (1-p)^(1/365)

since the probability of someone *taking a plane any given day* is 1- the probability of someone *not taking a plane any given day*, the final answer is
1-((1-p)^(1/365))

Comment: Could you describe your events more clearly?  For instance, does "a person taking a plane" refer to some *particular* person or to *any* person?  And then you do need to make explicit your key assumptions, such as that these daily events are independent (which is required to  justify your multiplications).  Finally, what question are you responding to with your "final answer"?